# how to show name of file selected throught add file button

Tags: javascript, php

```html
<span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
         <b>+ Add Video File </b> <input type="file" id="file2" name="file2" required>
    </span>
    <br><br>
```

how to show name of file which get selected through add file

Comment: Please specify in which language you want to get this ?

Comment: in php javascript, jquery

Comment: The control itself shows the file name of the selected file. Where do you want it shown? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that OP wants to do this in `JavaScript`...

After file selection there is `change` event triggered on input.
Input object contains `files` property with `FileList`, which is array type of object. From there you can extract file name and insert it into HTML for display purposes.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0ss5g61m/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
        if ( isset( $_POST['Submit'] ) ) {
           $file_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];}
           echo $file_name; 
        }
?>
```

**NOTE** Make sure that you use `"enctype='multipart/form-data"` in form tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery, use the following code

```
<span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
<b>+ Add Video File </b> <input type="file" id="file2" name="file2" required> 
<span id="filename"> </span>
</span>
<br><br>

<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#file2').on('change', function(){
var filename = $(this).val();
$('#filename').html(filename);
});
});
</script>
```